# LASTNONBLANK not working as expected in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a model fact table 'Factory Open Order Snapshot' with relationship to Date dimension on it's snapshot_date_key, I have checked that everything marries up in the datawarehouse and double checked that the data should as expected.

However, I have this measure below, the old version is from Azure Analysis Services and works just fine with all the same relationships, BUT in power BI it periodically returns blanks that cannot be explained. So much so that I had to switch to the bottom NEW version and abandon a callout to Date dimension altogeher.

```
Old:

Factory Open Order Quantity = CALCULATE (

   SUM ( 'Factory Open Order Snapshot'[OrderQuantityInOrderUnitofMeasure] ),

   LASTNONBLANK (

       **'Date'[Date]**,

       CALCULATE (

           SUM ( 'Factory Open Order Snapshot'[OrderQuantityInOrderUnitofMeasure] )

       )

   )

)

 

 

New:

Factory Open Order Quantity = CALCULATE (

   SUM ( 'Factory Open Order Snapshot'[OrderQuantityInOrderUnitofMeasure] ),

   LASTNONBLANK (

       **'Factory Open Order Snapshot'[SnapshotDate]**,

       CALCULATE (

           SUM ( 'Factory Open Order Snapshot'[OrderQuantityInOrderUnitofMeasure] )

       )

   )

)
```

Looking at the source data, and pulling out all the columns THERE is data that should have the result in the middle column (NEW) but instead it is blank as in the red box column:
[image]

Why is this the case? Is there something different under the hood in Power BI with how it deals with LASTNONBLANK and references to other tables?